# Importing github project into Eclipse (getting nesting error)

Tags: java, eclipse

I've started a fresh project in Eclipse and I would like to use Knicker (https://github.com/jeremybrooks/knicker) libraries in my project. I've followed the first three steps in this howto guide (http://equallytrue.blogspot.ca/2011/11/how-to-import-non-eclipse-github.html).

Now I can see both projects in the Eclipse Package Explorer. However I still get import errors in my original project (with the red x beside my java filename) and the Knicker Master project has a yellow cylinder beside each folder icon, with no explanation as to what this means in Eclipse.

When I try to remove and add the knicker/src folder under Java Build Path -> Add Class Folder I get "Cannot nest 'knicker/src' inside library 'knicker'".

How do I use the Knicker project in my Classpath? And what do those yellow cylinders mean?

Answer (score 1):

The yellow cylinder denotes that the folders/files are in sync with the Source Control management system, which is Git in your case.

If you wish to use the Knicker libraries, you do not need to fork/clone the source code. You can 
1. Get the jar and add it to your project classpath (Right click on project -> BuildPath-> Configure BuildPath -> Libraries -> Add external jar)
                      OR
2. add it as a maven or gradle dependency, if your project uses either of them.

Since you have already have the Knickers project in eclipse, you can add it to your project's classpath (Right click on project -> BuildPath-> Configure BuildPath -> Projects -> Add)

Comment: Thanks for the reply - however when I go to add a required project to the build path, there's nothing listed. I can't select any projects to add. However, I managed to get the jar from the Maven Repository and successfully add that to my project, so thanks for suggesting that route!

Comment: Bro I totally did but Stackoverflow won't show it because my "reputation" isn't high enough to change the publicly displayed score :(